# Generate Formulas in doxygen out of expression

Tags: python, documentation, doxygen, formulas, pyomo

I have got an optimization function that I want in written form in my documentation by using doxygen (I am using the latest release 1.8.14). Is there any possibility to generate automatically the equation out of the expression used in the objective function of my pyomo model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doxygen won't be able to directly get the optimized function from the objective function of the (unknown) pyomo model. The information has to be written out in some way that it can be used by doxygen.

The output can be in a number of forms:

Create a special command and use this in the code and create (as export from the model) an alias (see doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile), the tag `ALIASES`). This alias can that be added to the Doxyfile (see also the FAQ [Can I configure doxygen from the command line?](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#faq_cmdline%20%22Can%20I%20configure%20doxygen%20from%20the%20command%20line?%22))

Another, probably better and easier, possibility is to export the formula to a file (including the doxygen formula start and end tags) and use the command `\includedoc` to include the formula in the documentation.